# On the Cisco AIR models, what is the definition of radio reset code 71?

Tags: cisco, wireless, cisco-ios, aironet

We are using the Autonomous mode...

Cisco IOS Software, C1040 Software (C1140-K9W7-M), Version 15.2(4)JA1, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)

```
ap#sh controllers do1 radio-reset 
Last radio reset code: 71
Radio resets - total:22 retries:0 failed:0
Reset Stats: Start Cnt: 3, Recovery: Cnt 1, Last Ret: 0, Fails: 0, Recvry Status: Stalled NO, In Prog NO
   Code/Count: 37/00016 2 67/00001 0 68/00004 0 71/00001 BE8D
```

[Cisco Aironet 3700 Series - AP Radio Reset Codes](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/wireless/aironet-3700-series/117869-technote-ap-00.html) is the only link I can find with reference infomation regarding radio codes....

Comment: You might want to update your question with more details, such as AP model (presumably 3702 but that is just a guess based on your link), firmware, more details about the issue - how often it happens, what has recently changed, using a WLC or using autonomous mode, etc.

Comment: @legioxi Thanks, the post has been updated.

Comment: Can you try upgrading to the latest firmware version first and see if the issue persists? 15.2.4-JB5(ED) as of this writing.

It would appear that radio reset code 71 is undocumented.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I have gleaned from the Cisco support pages.

> Status 71: Reset to update radio status on WLC. Also usually done upon
>   AP joining the WLC after boot up.

<sup>*[Cisco Support Community - %LINK-3-UPDOWN: Interface Dot11Radio0, changed state to down](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11364506/link-3-updown-interface-dot11radio0-changed-state-down#comment-6988651)*</sup>